# Convert YouTube API duration (ISO 8601 duration in the format) to h:m:s , when format without "T" in javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube, formatting, duration

I have checked most of similar questions, and this one was helpfull

```
> function parseDuration(PT) {   var output = [];   var durationInSec =
> 0;   var matches =
> PT.match(/P(?:(\d*)Y)?(?:(\d*)M)?(?:(\d*)W)?(?:(\d*)D)?T(?:(\d*)H)?(?:(\d*)M)?(?:(\d*)S)?/i);
> var parts = [
>     { // years
>       pos: 1,
>       multiplier: 86400 * 365
>     },
>     { // months
>       pos: 2,
>       multiplier: 86400 * 30
>     },
>     { // weeks
>       pos: 3,
>       multiplier: 604800
>     },
>     { // days
>       pos: 4,
>       multiplier: 86400
>     },
>     { // hours
>       pos: 5,
>       multiplier: 3600
>     },
>     { // minutes
>       pos: 6,
>       multiplier: 60
>     },
>     { // seconds
>       pos: 7,
>       multiplier: 1
>     }   ];
>      for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
>     if (typeof matches[parts[i].pos] != 'undefined') {
>       durationInSec += parseInt(matches[parts[i].pos]) * parts[i].multiplier;
>     }   }
>      // Hours extraction   if (durationInSec > 3599) {
>     output.push(parseInt(durationInSec / 3600));
>     durationInSec %= 3600;   }   if (durationInSec >= 86399) {
>     output.push("24:00");    }     // Minutes extraction with leading zero   output.push(('0' + parseInt(durationInSec / 60)).slice(-2));  
> // Seconds extraction with leading zero   output.push(('0' +
> durationInSec % 60).slice(-2));
>      return output.join(':'); };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Daugilas/kbeb0p99/1/ answer by  @Daugilas Kakaras

But I found one video with format P1D (one day), without "T", and function above can't format it.

Comment: PT1D - doesn't works too, the same as P1D, I have tried...

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I thought you were having issues with "P1H", but it seems you're having issues with "P1D", as you wrote in the OP. Silly me… you just need `T?`.

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure the values for year and month are suitable, there should be some allowance for leap years and differing month lengths, see [*ISO 8601 duration and time stamps in SCORM 2004*](http://www.ostyn.com/standards/scorm/samples/ISOTimeForSCORM.htm#durationfmt), which suggests `1 month = ((365 * 4) + 1)/48 days` and uses `1 year = 365.25 days`, whereas the code in the OP uses 30 days and 365 days respectively (so 12 months != 1 year by a 5.25 days).

Answer (score 2):

To fix the code in the OP, you need to make the T optional, so replace `T` with `T?`.

The values used for year and month don't seem suitable (see [*ISO 8601 duration and time stamps in SCORM 2004*](http://www.ostyn.com/standards/scorm/samples/ISOTimeForSCORM.htm#durationfmt)), the number of days in a year is better approimated as `365.25 days` and in one month as `365.25 * 4 / 48 days`, though doing arithmetic with durations longer than 1 month is very problematic with simplistic functions like these.

The following is an alternative function, it doesn't test the input string for validity which it probably should and the conversion of milliseconds to h:mm:ss.sss should be a separate function, but I'll leave that to others.

```js
/*   @param {string} s - ISO8601 format duration
**
**                       P[yY][mM][dD][T[hH][mM][s[.s]S]]
**
**   @returns {string} - time in h:mm:ss format
**
**   1 year is 365.25 days
**   1 months is averaged over 4 years: (365*4+1)/48
**/
function convertISODurationToHMS(s) {
  var T = 'date';
  var d = 8.64e7;
  var h = d/24;
  var m = h/60;
  var multipliers = {date: {y:d*365.25, m:d*(365*4+1)/48, d:d},
                     time: {h:h, m:m, s:1000}};
  var re = /[^a-z]+|[a-z]/gi;

  // Tokenise with match, then process with reduce
  var time = s.toLowerCase().match(/p|t|\d+\.?\d*[ymdhs]/ig).reduce(function(ms, v) {
    if (v == 'p') return ms;
    if (v == 't') {
      T = 'time';
      return ms;
    }
    var b = v.match(re);
    return ms + b[0] * multipliers[T][b[1]];
  }, 0);
  
  // Converting ms to h:mm:ss should be a separate function
  return (time/h|0) + ':'
       + ('0' + ((time%h / m) |0)).slice(-2) + ':'
       + ('0' + (time%m/1000).toFixed(3)).slice(-6);
}

// Some tests
['P1D',
 'PT1M',
 'PT1M2.3S',
 'P1DT1H1M2.345S',
 'P1DT1H1M2.34S',
  'P1M',
  'P1YT1H1M56.234S']
  .forEach(function(v){
   document.write(v + ': ' + convertISODurationToHMS(v) + '<br>');
 });
```